# Аллокация памяти в Vulkan API с VK_EXT_external_memory_host расширением выводит ErrorOutOfDeviceMemory

Tags: c++, изображения, память, xorg, vulkan

имеется archlinux, nvidia gtx1650, nvidia-465 drivers, vulkan 1.2.

имеется [код](https://github.com/safocl/vulkan_test/blob/3c21679b531311d32591ad0de56be13492acd742/src/vulkanrender.cpp#L684), которым я хочу экспортировать картинку из Xorg на GPU через расширение `VK_EXT_external_memory_host`. Данное расширение поддержано в указанных драйверах. Однако получаю ошибку ErrorOutOfDeviceMemory.

[Полный лог выполнения программы.](http://ix.io/3qNI)

имеется предположение, что данное поведение получается из-за неправильно выравненной памяти по переданному указателю -- данную теорию еще не проверял, но однако почему тогда именно указанная ошибка выводится, вместо, скажем, `VK_ERROR_INVALID_EXTERNAL_HANDLE`...

и еще -- драйвер моей видяхи не предоставляет доступной памяти с нужными memoryTypeIndex и флагом `{ DeviceLocal }`, тоесть есть память которая только `{ HostVisible | HostCoherent }`, ну или с добавлением `{ HostCached }`.

на всякий случай предоставляю [vulkaninfo.html](http://ix.io/3qO1)

Comment: Было бы странно возвращать VK_ERROR_INVALID_EXTERNAL_HANDLE, когда с этим дескриптором все хорошо. А других кодов ошибок кроме VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY для этого расширения не заявлено. Ну и да, указатель обязательно должен быть выровнен, и это следует в обязательном порядке проверять ДО вызова этой функции.

Comment: ну как я понимаю у меня как раз 4КБ выравнивание сейчас в системе -- минимально допустимое выравнивание для такой аллокации

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется я понял в чем проблема -- похоже она в выделенной памяти -- `vkImportMemoryHostPointerInfoEXT` структура требует, что бы поинтер переданный в нее указывал на область памяти размером ровно столько байт, сколько указано после в выделении `vkAllocateMemory()` -- а он для данного случая должен быть кратным значению выравнивания.

То есть, при импорте он пытается всю память начиная от адреса указателя скопировать размером, которое указано в аллокации. Но я выделяю память не кратно значению выравнивания, а получается обычно чуть меньше, из-за чего `vulkan api` начинает использовать чужую память за пределами того куска памяти, которое было выделено под image.

Надо попробовать выделять память кратно значению выравнивания.

Answer (score 0):

да -- все теперь работает -- сделал выделения памяти кратно выравниванию, указываю этот размер в структуре выделения памяти vulkan и все отлично теперь -- картинки импортятся в vulkan api